# How to switch off Resharper check for XML commets?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [missing xml comment for publicly visible type or member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203863/missing-xml-comment-for-publicly-visible-type-or-member)

I don't know how I did it but suddenly Resharper is underlying all public methods (blue underline) and classes saying `Missing XML comment for publicly visible...` followed by `class` or `member` and name. How (and where) can is disable this ? Cannot find it in Resharpers options (I have tried `ReSharper -> Options -> Inspection Severity`).

Comment: This is most probably because you have turned on "generate xml documentation" in the project properties.

Comment: I have voted to close this question as duplicate (of the question linked by Jon). Please consider checking the linked question and voting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ReSharper checks for current build settings if generation on XML-doc file is enabled during build. If XML generation is disabled, this warning will not be fired. Otherwise, C# compiler will fire that warning (CS1591), and thus ReSharper will fire it too

Comment: Been banging my head around on this problem for a bit. Thank you!