# WCF - Add service reference XML docs

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, xml-documentation

We have our projects set to build documentation files, but the Add Service Reference tool in Visual Studio creates files with no XML docs. This results in a ton of build warnings, which we'd like to avoid.

Is there a way to get Add Service Reference to generate XML docs? Or, if not, is there a way to modify a T4 template that generates service references?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe adding a service reference can generate the xml comments for you. See [XML Comments not appearing in WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239327/xml-comments-not-appearing-in-wcf-service) for more information on that.

Your best bet is to turn the warning level down or off for the xml comment missing. In visual studio I think this will help ([Visual Studio Disabling Missing XML Comment Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982525/visual-studio-disabling-missing-xml-comment-warning)).

If you are using a tool such as resharper you can ignore the entire file (http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/06/preventing-items-from-being-analyzed-in-resharper/) or just ignore the xml comment warnings ([How to switch off Resharper check for XML commets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773890/how-to-switch-off-resharper-check-for-xml-commets)).