# Ignore property in XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add an element to an entity that is derived from a base class. The entity extends the base class which doesn't have a custom error message that I can set. When I added the element I got a warning for:

> Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member

When I added the `[XmlIgnore]` to the property though and re-built the project that contains all the entities I am still receiving this message. So is it enough to just add the `[XmlIgnore]` and forget about that message or is there something else I need to do?

[image]

Comment: I think you are misusing XmlIgnore attribute. See here for a number of ways to deal with your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203863/missing-xml-comment-for-publicly-visible-type-or-member I don't think XML comments are even serialized, but rather used for generating APIs to your assemblies, so you may be mixing up two different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its just warning you that you haven't put in a comment against the string.

If you want to get rid of it just add a comment.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This property does something
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string CustomErrorMessageADF { get; set; }
```

Edit: 
The XML Comments can be added to anything within visual studio by just typing /// above any class, property or method. Visual Studio will automatically add in the other details. 
You can then add comments in which allow them to be visible via Intellisense. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx