# How do I force document comment

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a SDK that few developers can edit and add new methods.
I want to force each developer that adds a new function to add documented comment.
the documented comment should include the supported version of this method.
for the summary I added XML documentation file and it works for me (the build fails if no documented comment)
I still have no solution for the supported version comment

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Function1 description
    /// </summary>
    /// <**supportedSince**>Version 5.6</**supportedSince**>
    public List<string> Function1{ get; set; }
```

Comment: AFAIK, stylecop can do this. You can setup pre-commit/pre-push hook in SCM you use.

Answer (score 2):

[Warning CS1591](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk18c1w9.aspx) is generated when [XML comments are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203863/missing-xml-comment-for-publicly-visible-type-or-member)

You can treat that individual warning as an error - this has to be done for each project which uses the source-code in question. See [/warnaserror](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/406xhdz3.aspx)

So you could add this compiler option to each project's settings:

```
  /warnaserror:1591
```

Comment: This will only force them to add a comment. It won't force them to add a comment that is _actually useful or meaningful_.

Comment: The eternal problem. I suppose you will have to read the comments and decide on their meaning and usefulness, and then fire the programmers who are refusing to cooperate. That's why they pay team leaders and development managers the big bucks.

Comment: Other techniques can include code reviews (either on all changes or occasional ones) and mentoring new team members on the importance of good documentation. Or, the developers who write the SDK act as first-line support for the consumers of it. Poor documentation may result in more support queries, which reinforces the importance of well-written, usable documentation.

Comment: That sounds like persuasion rather than force :-)